# xterm argument terminal close immediatley

Tags: xterm, nmap

i went to open xterm with argument to execute nmap command and i am try this method

```
$ xterm -e nmap 74.125.130.100
```

xterm is open and it's is execute Nmap command but xterm immediately close after complete is task. and this is a problem. i went to be open to see a output, if any ubuntu guy know's how to resolve this issue please  post it solution and command thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the -hold option.

i.e. `xterm -hold -e nmap 74.125.130.100`

Comment: thanks adonis for your solution it is reaaly help for me..!